# Injection from tuples of subsets to others

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-proofs

Let $k$ be an integer and $[k] = \{1,2,...,k\}$. Let $\mathcal{A}$ be the set of tuples $(I_1, I_2, ..., I_{k+1})$ such that for all $j$, $I_j \subseteq  [k]$ and $|I_j|$ is even. Also, let $\mathcal{A}_i$ be the subset of $\mathcal{A}$ such that $|I_1| + |I_2| + ... + |I_{k+1}| = i$. In perticular, $\mathcal{A}_i = \emptyset$ if $i$ is odd.

Let $\mathcal{B}$ be defined the same way, but interchanging the roles of $k$ and $k+1$. So, it is the set of tuples $(I_1, I_2, ..., I_{k})$ such that for all $j$, $I_j \subseteq  [k+1]$ and $|I_j|$ is even. Define $\mathcal{B}_i$ analogously.

I want to show that for all $i \leq k^2-1$, $i$ even, there is an injection $\mathcal{A}_i \rightarrow \mathcal{B}_i$. I have been able to show that $|\mathcal{A}_i| \leq |\mathcal{B}_i|$, but I'm looking for a combinatorial proof, if one exists.

**What I tried so far**

One obvious guess would be to send $(I_1, I_2, ..., I_{k+1})$ to $(I_1', I_2', ..., I_k')$, where $I_j' = I_j \cup \{k+1\}$ if $j \in I_{k+1}$ and $I_j' = I_j$ else. But then, some of the subsets would not be of even size.

To correct it, we can use the bijection $I \mapsto I \triangle \{1\}$ between subsets of odd size and those of even size, where $\triangle$ is the symmetric difference. So, we add $1$ to $I$ if $1 \not\in I$, and substract $1$ from $I$ if $1 \in I$. But then, the total sum of the sizes of $(I_1, I_2, ..., I_{k+1})$ is changed.

Does anyone know of an injection that would both preserve the even size of all subsets and the total size of the subsets in the tuple?

**Example**

Let $k=3$. An element of $\mathcal{A}_6$ is

$$ (\{1,2\}, \emptyset, \{2,3\} , \{2,3\}) $$

Using what I tried so far, the first injection would send it to

$$ (\{1,2\}, \{4\}, \{2,3,4\}) $$.

Using the symmetric difference with $\{1\}$ on subsets of odd size (those who contain $4$), we obtain

$$ (\{1,2\}, \{1,4\}, \{1,2,3,4\}) $$

But then, this tuple is in $\mathcal{B}_8$, and not in $\mathcal{B}_6$, which is what I would like.

Is there a way to construct such an injection that preserves the sum of the sizes of the subsets?

Comment: You know that it is true, and you want to prove it, right?

Comment: I have been able to prove that it is true numerically (i.e. the size of the sets are smaller or equal), but the proof is horrible and I'm looking for something elegant.

Comment: So, let's say, there is a numerical evidence that it should be true..

Comment: Yes, I'll edit the post to reflect that

Comment: Equivalently, if you let $M_{p,q}^i$ be the set of $p\times q$ matrices with entries in $\{0,1\}$ with exactly $i$ ones and an even number of ones in each row, then you are trying to find an injection from $M^i_{k+1,k}$ to $M^i_{k,k+1}$.